# Target debug_unpack_ios failed

Tags: flutter, ios-simulator

I wasn't coding flutter a few months. After that i made a software update and now i'm using macos sonoma and xcode 15. Now my projects not working?. I opened new project and it's not working too on ios simulator but when i use android simulator it's working. I have some error messages. How can i fix it?
Error (Xcode): Target debug_unpack_ios failed: Exception: Failed to codesign with identity -
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro.
btw when i opened it on xcode it's working.

I tried most of the things which is at the stackoverflow but still not working.